# What rules of index notation would be used to write these expressions in vector form?

Tags: notation, vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose you had the expressions $u_{j} \frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}$ and $u_{j} \frac{\partial u_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}$.

Explaining the rules/method used, how would you express these in vector form?

Comment: equation means that symbol of equal, $=$, should be used

Comment: What would they be then, expressions?

Comment: yes, or well formed formulas

Answer (score 0):

The first expression is
\begin{align*}
u_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} &= (\mathbf u \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)u_i \\
&= [(\mathbf u \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)\mathbf u]_i.
\end{align*}

The second expression is
\begin{align*}
u_j \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} &= \frac 12 \left(u_j \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} + \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} u_j \right)\\
&= \frac 12 \partial_i (\mathbf u \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf u) \\
&= \left[\frac 12 \boldsymbol \nabla (\mathbf u \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf u)\right]_i,
\end{align*} by the product rule.